# Simplest way to convert single space words to more than 1 space

Tags: python, regex

Suppose I have the string:

```
This  is  12345  string  with  code  5435 / 23566  on  13/12/2018 SIN, SGD   Ok, KL
```

I want:

```
This  is  12345  string  with  code  5435 / 23566  on  13/12/2018  SIN, SGD   Ok, KL
```

Difference being the first one has just 1 single space between "13/12/2018" and "SIN, SGD" while the second makes it more than 1 space.

A word is defined as any alphanumeric character with space on either side (unless its the first or last word). If there is a comma in between or / in between then that is considered part of same word. For ex

"SIN, SGD" or "Ok, KL" or "5435 / 23566" is considered one word as / or , is considered part of same word.

So adding more than one space between words and keeping the space inside words as single space so that when I do

```
re.split(r'\s{2,}', s.strip)
```

on the final string, I should get:

```
['This',
 'is',
 '12345',
 'string',
 'with',
 'code',
 '5435 / 23566',
 'on',
 '13/12/2018',
 'SIN, SGD',
 'Ok, KL']
```

Tried this:

```
re.sub("\b ", "\s{2,}", s)
```

throws an error

```
bad escape \s at position 0
```

Comment: It's not really clear which single spaces you want to make double spaces. For example `Ok, KL` stays as a single space. Why? What is special about `13/12/2018  SIN`?

Comment: yes. See the output. It remains same. This is one word. I want to replace single space BETWEEN words to multi space. SO that when I do split on final output it should give the result as shown above for list

Comment: `Ok, KL` is not one word by any definition of "word" I have ever seen.

Comment: I put that example there so that its clear that things which have / or , is treated as one word and the space between them shouldn't be made double.

Comment: Maybe you just want `re.sub(r'\b\s\b', '    ', s)`?

Comment: In your code your second parameter does not have closing `"` (double quote).

Comment: doesn't help for both.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working Example

```
s="This  is  12345  string  with  code  5435 / 23566  on  13/12/2018 SIN, SGD   Ok, KL"  
print(s.replace(" ","  "))
```

in the above example, it will replace single space with double space.
I hope this will work fine

Comment: this will replace all single space with double. I want to replace single between words with double and a word is defined by anything (alphabets, ",", "\" or numbers). So SIN, SGD above is one word. Same for Ok, KL. Same for 5435 / 23566. 

There is only one space between 13/12/2018 SIN SGD. I want two space there like others

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using split, you could match all the values:

```
\w+(?:(?:, | */ *)\w+)*
```

- `\w+` Match 1+ word chars
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `(?:, | */ *)` Match either a comma and space OR match `/` between optional spaces
  - `\w+` Match 1+ word chars
- `)*` Close group and repeat 0+ times

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/XREpLc/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/HJkxTq)

*Example code*

```
import re

regex = r"\w+(?:(?:, | */ *)\w+)*"
test_str = "This  is  12345  string  with  code  5435 / 23566  on  13/12/2018 SIN, SGD   Ok, KL"

print(re.findall(regex, test_str))
```

*Output*

```
[
    'This'
    'is'
    '12345'
    'string'
    'with'
    'code'
    '5435 / 23566'
    'on'
    '13/12/2018'
    'SIN SGD'
    'Ok KL'
]
```